# iPad app supporting RemoteApp RDP protocol?

Tags: ipad, remote-desktop

Is there an iPad out there than can connect to Terminal Services RemoteApp?

See [TechNet article explaning RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The full version of Spark View supports RemoteApp. You can try it here:

http://www.remotespark.com:8080

You'll have to install the gateway to make your internal network accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [iTap RDP](http://itap-mobile.com/itap-rdp) for 2 years now to log in to our companies TS Gateway, and it works very well.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you provide some more details here about why are you recommending this as a solution? What do you like about this app? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only iOS app I'm aware of that advertises TS RemoteApp is [WinAdmin Remote Desktop](http://itunes.apple.com/app/winadmin-remote-desktop/id284963046?mt=8#). It's not universal so it runs on the 1x reduced area on the iPad or pixel doubling. Not at all ideal so I hope someone else has a better suggestion (or this developer makes a iPad or universal version of the app).

You might also contact [iTap Mobile](http://itap-mobile.com/itap-rdp/details) - their product might support TS gateway as an in app purchase once you have bought [iTap RDP](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itap-rdp-remote-desktop-for/id317062064?mt=8)

Comment: I checked with iTap, they don't support it and have no immediate plans to add support.

Comment: I don't see any mention of TS RemoteApp in WinAdmin's iTunes description. Could you point me to where you saw it?

Comment: It was on a blog post that I had saved in instapaper - the article now seems to have been edited. It looks like my information was bad. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you need remote access from iPads to Terminal Server, you can try Ericom AccessToGo, a free RDP client for iPad, iPhone and Android devices.

If you also want to speed up RDP for your iPad user, you can use AccessToGo with Ericom's Blaze server (a commercial, not free product).  That makes AccessToGo the fastest RDP client for mobile devices for working with graphic applications over a remote connection.

For more information about AccessToGo, visit:
http://www.ericom.com/mobile.asp?URL_ID=708

Comment: since you are clearly advertising, could you clarify whether AccessToGo supports RemoteApp?

Answer (score 0):

To Everyone:
The question is referencing RemoteApp support, not just an RDP connection.

I use iTap RDP, which works amazingly well for standard RDP access.  It does have an option to launch a program, but this is not RemoteApp.  I believe this feature is supposed to support program launching as done in previous versions of the RDP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider getting a free trial of Splashtop Enterprise... Splashtop's SplashApp real-time transcode RDP 8/7/6 protocol to Splashtop protocol... so this means that ALL RDP features including RemoteApp and RDP8's higher performance capability are fully supported, and, Splashtop apps are available for iPad/iPhone, Android, Blackberry, Linux, MAC, WinRT, Windows Phone, etc... so any device can have full remote access to Win 2008 / 2012 RDS / RemoteApp.   Splashtop optimizes for Intel, NVIDIA, AMD, and other chips so the performance is best-in-class (can even do remote 3D games :) ). http://www.splashtop.com/enterprise/
best, -mark (CEO Splashtop)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Thanks for disclosing your relationship to the product you mentioned. Nevertheless it would be helpful if your answer would not just be a marketing text to reduce the risk of having it flagged as spam by users visiting the site. See [How To Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) for ideas on how to improve your answer.